# FullCalendar - AgendaView Scroll Event (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to find the scroll event for the Agenda "Week" and "Day" views

This does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.fc-time-grid-container').scroll(function(){
        alert('scrolled!');
    });

});
```

Nor does this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('scroll', '.fc-time-grid-container', function(){
        alert('scrolled!');
    });

});
```

Also tried ".fc-widget-content", ".fc-body" and ".fc-agendaWeek-view"

http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: `$(".fc-time-grid-container").scroll(function(){alert("scrolled")});` works for me on Chrome. Make sure FC is initialized first.

Comment: Had no luck with: $(function () {

    $(".fc-time-grid-container").scroll(function(){alert("scrolled")});

});  Is there a scrollTop change event?

Comment: After the page has loaded, try pasting the above code into the browser's console and running it.